# How do I remove empty page between a chapter when include?

Tags: chapters, include

\let\cleardoublepage\clearpage this line of code does not avoid it in texstudion? I know that the Texstudio is a powerful environment to write a report.
How would avoid black page between the chapters?

Comment: try `\input` instead `\include`

Comment: Welcome to TEX.SE! Would you please explain your question clearly? What performance would you want and what you do in your source code? :)

Comment: Your problem is unrelated to texstudio (that is just the editor you are using to write the file) `\include` always starts a new page as does `\chapter` so you do not normally get a blank page from `\include` (as long as `\chapter` command is in the included file not before the `\include`) you will get one from `\chapter` if you are using `[twoside]` unless you specify `[openany]`

Comment: Thank you!! I am writing my thesis report. And Want to add a list of abbreviations before chapter one and after the contents.    For example, include{preliminary-pages/ACRONYMS}.

Comment: You are not providing enough information for anyone to help, your question should have a complete small test file that shows the problem.